# Something in the way she knows

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I don’t understand what the «Something in the way she knows» and «Something in the things she shows me» means in the song «Something» by the Beatles.

Excerpt from the song:

> Something in the way she knows 
>   And all I have to do is think of her 
>   Something in the things she shows me 
>   I don't want to leave her now 
>   You know I believe and how

Comment: The song is about the _something_ that makes the singer love her. That something is in all the things he mentions. How to exactly interpret it is up to the reader / listener. A simple way to say it might be _I like how she knows things, and I like what she shows me_.

Comment: If you could include more context, *ie* the complete sentences  that these phrases are part of,   it might be easier to give you an answer. In other words, please supply more context.

Comment: As JavaLatte suggests, we can use the word **something** to mean "I am unable to say exactly what it is, at least not right now. I cannot *put my finger on it*." Compare: "*Something* about this crime scene seems all wrong."  The detective is noticing that some aspect of the scene is awry, though he cannot identify what it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one, because **the lyrics do not always exactly correspond to complete thoughts** or complete sentences. It may be helpful to look at other lyrics in "Something", to understand exactly what the author is saying.

> Something in the way she moves 
>   Attracts me like no other lover

- The author does not know exactly what causes him to be attracted to her, more than any of his other "lovers". He knows that it is related to how "she moves". It could be the way she walks, holds her hands, or dances.

[image: Dancing couple]

> Something in the way she woos me

- There is something special, or awesome, about the way that "she woos me" (she tries to gain his love), but the author does not know exactly what.

> Somewhere in her smile she knows 
>   That I don't need no other lover

- The author knows that *she* knows that he only needs her, and he recognizes this concept through the way that she smiles. Perhaps her smile is confident or seductive.

[image]

Now let's look at your verse.

> Something in the way she knows 
>   And all I have to do is think of her 
>   Something in the things she shows me 
>   I don't want to leave her now 
>   You know I believe and how

- *Something in the way she knows* : I believe this is a reference to "Somewhere in her smile she knows", how she *knows* that he is interested in her.
- *Something in the things she shows me* : This is more vague. "The things she shows me" could be her smile, the way she talks, the way she moves, or any other quality that the author mentions in the songs.

**The most important takeaway: the author does not seem to form a complete thought. Rather, he seems to be listing her qualities as he thinks about her.**

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar theme in the title of the film [There's something about Mary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129387/). In both cases, there is something special about a particular woman that attracts a particular man (in the song) or a lot of men (in the film).

There is a saying **Beauty is in the eye of the beholder** which means that different people find different things attractive. Sometimes it's not easy to describe what exactly you find attractive about a person- it's just **something**.